# How to count number of words in a sentence in Assembly.

Tags: assembly, lc3

Sorry, this is the first time posting on stackoverflow so excuse me for any improper edicts. I've posted my LC-3 assembly code that asks user for a sentence and a word. Then the program checks how many times that `word` comes up in the sentence; then outputs the counter. I'm pretty sure my issue is that the two strings include ether `space` or `enter` so its not a match.

Also, I have not implemented the overall counter yet, and thanks in advance for the help.

```
.ORIG X3000

LEA R2, SENTENCE    
LD R4, COUNTER     
LD R6, END_COUNTER        
LEA R3, USER_WORD       
LEA R0, PROMPT                                  
PUTS                                    
AND R0, R0, #0                              

;---------GET SENTENCE FROM USER-------------------------        

GET_ANOTHER_CHAR:                           
GETC                                     
OUT                                  
STR R0, R2, #0                              
ADD R2, R2, #1                              
ADD R0, R0, #-10                            
BRz GET_WORD_FROM_USER                              
BRnp GET_ANOTHER_CHAR                               

;---------GET WORD FROM USER-----------------------------     

GET_WORD_FROM_USER:                             
LEA R0, PROMPT_TWO                              
PUTS                                    
ANOTHER_LETTER_WORD:    
AND R0, R0, #0                              
GETC                                    
OUT                                 
STR R0, R3, #0                              
ADD R3, R3, #1                              
ADD R0, R0, #-10                             
BRz COMPARE_BOTH                                
ADD R4, R4, #1                              
BRnp ANOTHER_LETTER_WORD                            

;-------COMPARE EACH WORD IN THE SENTENCE----------------   

COMPARE_BOTH:                                   
AND R0, R0, #0                              
AND R5, R5, #0                              
LDR R0, R2, #0                              
BRz END_OF_SENTENCE                         
LDR R5, R3, #0                              
NOT R5, R5                              
ADD R5, R5, #1                              
ADD R5, R0, R5                               
BRz LETTERS_MATCHED                         
ADD R2, R2, #1                                  
BRnp COMPARE_BOTH                               
BRz END_OF_SENTENCE                         

;-----COMPARE EACH LETTER-------------------------------       

LETTERS_MATCHED:         
ADD R4, R4, #-1                                     
BRz WORD_MATCHES                                    
AND R0, R0, #0                                      
AND R5, R5, #0                                  
ADD R2, R2, #1                                  
ADD R3, R3, #1                                  
LDR R0, R2, #0                                  
LDR R5, R3, #0                                  
NOT R5, R5                                      
ADD R5, R5, #1                                  
ADD R5, R0, R5                                  
BRz LETTERS_MATCHED                                 
BRnp COMPARE_BOTH                               

;------WORD MATCHES------------------------------------      

WORD_MATCHES:     
AND R0, R0, #0                                  
ADD R6, R6, #1                                  
ADD R2, R2, #1                              
LDR R0, R2, #0                               
BRz PROGRAM_FINISH                           
BRnp COMPARE_BOTH                             

PROGRAM_FINISH:    
AND R0, R0, #0                                  
LEA R0, PROMPT_THREE                             
PUTS                                    
HALT                                        

END_OF_SENTENCE:    
AND R0, R0, #0                                      
LEA R0, PROMPT_FOUR                             
PUTS                                        
HALT    

PROMPT .stringz "Enter some text(max 300 characters) \n"      
PROMPT_TWO .stringz "What word are you looking for? \n"      
PROMPT_THREE .stringz "match!"      
PROMPT_FOUR .stringz "no match!"      
SPACE .fill #-32      
COUNTER .fill #0       
END_COUNTER .fill #0      
USER_WORD .blkw 10     
SENTENCE .blkw 300    

.END
```

---

Comment: You should let us know what the output is and what output you expect, as well as any tracing you've done.  The simulator for the LC3 is pretty awesome for stepping through code, and will help narrow down your problem.  Then, we can talk easier about the parts of the code that aren't working, rather than searching through the entire thing.

Answer (score 0):

In COMPARE_BOTH you increment sentence pointer (R2) but not word pointer (R3), so you enter
LETTERS_MATCHED with pointers "out of sync".

I don't know if there is something more, but check that first.

It's a bit tedious to read with so "sparse" comments - especially about register usage.